# Unexpected identifier while

Tags: javascript, php

I have an unexpected code error but I can't identify it.

Code:

```
$('#add1').click(function(){
   var html = '<tr>';
   html += '<td contenteditable ><input type="date" class="input-date" id="data1"/></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable><input type="text" class="input-day" id="data2"/></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable ><input type="time" id="data3"/></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable><input type="time"  id="data4"/></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable><select id="data5"><option></option><?php
   $sql = "SELECT nome FROM raddb.Utente ORDER BY nome ASC";
   $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
   while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
   echo "<option value=".$ln['nome'].">".$ln['nome']."</option>";
   }?></select></td>';
   html += '</tr>';
  });
```

Within my role this echo line is giving unexpected error:

```
echo "<option value=".$ln['nome'].">".$ln['nome']."</option>";
```

Full code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  dom: 'Bflrtip',
  fetch_data();

  function fetch_data()
  {
   var dataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({
       dom: 'Bflrtip',
    "processing" : true,
    "serverSide" : true,
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "iDisplayLength": 5,
        "oLanguage": {
    "sProcessing": "Aguarde enquanto os dados são carregados ...",
    "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registos por página",
    "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registo correspondente ao criterio encontrado",
    "sInfoEmtpy": "Exibindo 0 a 0 de 0 registos",
    "sInfo": "Exibindo de _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ registos",
    "sInfoFiltered": "",
    "sSearch": "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span>",
    "oPaginate": {
       "sFirst":    "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-fast-backward'></span>",
       "sPrevious": "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-backward'></span>",
       "sNext":     "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-forward'></span>",
       "sLast":     "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-fast-forward'></span>"
     }
    },
    buttons: [
      {
            extend: 'excel',
                text: 'excel',
                title: 'Consultas Semanais',

        },
        {
            extend: 'pdf',
                text: 'pdf',
                title: 'Consultas Semanais',

        },
        {
            extend: 'print',
                text: 'print',
                title: 'Consultas Semanais',
                customize: function ( win ) {
                    $(win.document.body)
                        .css( 'font-size', '10pt' );

                    $(win.document.body).find( 'table' )
                        .addClass( 'compact' )
                        .css( 'font-size', 'inherit' );
                }
        }
    ], 
    "order" : [],
    "ajax" : {
     url:"./fetchconsulta",
     type:"POST"
    }   
    });   
    }

    function update_data(id, column_name, value)
   {
   $.ajax({
    url:"./updateconsulta",
    method:"POST",
    data:{id:id, column_name:column_name, value:value},
    success:function(data)
    {
     $('#alert_message').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
    }
   });
   setInterval(function(){
    $('#alert_message').html('');
   }, 5000);
  }

  $(document).on('blur', '.update', function(){
   var id = $(this).data("id");
   var column_name = $(this).data("column");
   var value = $(this).text();
   update_data(id, column_name, value);
  });

  var semana = ["Domingo", "Segunda-Feira", "Terça-Feira", "Quarta-Feira", "Quinta-Feira", "Sexta-Feira", "Sábado"];

   $('#add1').click(function(){
   var html = '<tr>';
   html += '<td contenteditable ><input type="date" class="input-date" id="data1"/></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable><input type="text" class="input-day" id="data2"/></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable ><input type="time" id="data3"/></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable><input type="time"  id="data4"/></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable><select id="data5"><option></option><?php
   $sql = "SELECT nome FROM raddb.Utente ORDER BY nome ASC";
   $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
   while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
   echo "<option value=".$ln['nome'].">".$ln['nome']."</option>";
   }?></select></td>';
   html += '</tr>';
  });


});
```

Comment: In JavaScript, you need some indicator that a string is going to span multiple lines. You can't just start with a ' and then many lines later have another '. Use a \ or a '+ to span multiple lines - but I doubt this is what you want to do because it won't work anyway. You can't run PHP on the client.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: In the _full code_ at least `$conn` variable is nowehere assigned. This code is not "full"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right here on this line you have an opening PHP tag without closing the table cell and line of code:

```
html += '<td contenteditable><select id="data5"><option></option><?php
```

**EDIT** You want this, here is the whole block:

```
   html += '<td contenteditable><select id="data5"><option></option>';
   <?php
       $sql = "SELECT nome FROM raddb.Utente ORDER BY nome ASC";
       $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
       while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
          echo "<option value=".$ln['nome'].">".$ln['nome']."</option>";
       }
    ?>
   html += '</select></td>';
   html += '</tr>';
```

**BUT YOU HAVE AN ISSUE HERE**
You're trying to run PHP inside of a JavaScript command and that will not work. What you need to do, if you want to keep your function "as is", is to trigger an AJAX request to your PHP and return the information to be placed into the options in your markup. Therefore your code should be something like this:

```
html += '<td contenteditable><select id="data5"><option></option>';
$('#data5').load('options.php');
html += '</select></td>';
html += '</tr>';
```

With options.php being something like this:

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("HOST", "USER", "PW", "DATABASE");
    $sql = "SELECT nome FROM raddb.Utente ORDER BY nome ASC";
    $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
       while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
          echo "<option value=".$ln['nome'].">".$ln['nome']."</option>";
       }
    ?>
```

**BUT YOU MAY RUN INTO A TIMING ISSUE** because `#data5` may not exist when the AJAX returns the data from the PHP, so you must make sure `#data5` exists *before* the AJAX call is made.

Comment: if i check i close the line after closing select `html += '<td contenteditable><select id="data5"><option></option><?php
   $sql = "SELECT nome FROM raddb.Utente ORDER BY nome ASC";
   $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
   while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
   echo "<option value=".$ln['nome'].">".$ln['nome']."</option>";
   }?></select></td>';`

Comment: Update @BrunoPinto

Comment: I created the options file, changed js but returns this error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"

Comment: What do you mean, I didn't understand.

Comment: Can you run options.php?

Comment: I have already executed and is working properly the options.php

Comment: Can we talk in chat?

Answer (score 0):

You broke into multiple lines without escaping the new lines with '\'.

## So, if you want to add the php code into `html` variable. then, you can try this,,

Therefore, You can try adding '\',

```
$('#add1').click(function(){
   var html = '<tr>';
   html += '<td contenteditable ><input type="date" class="input-date" id="data1"/></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable><input type="text" class="input-day" id="data2"/></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable ><input type="time" id="data3"/></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable><input type="time"  id="data4"/></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable><select id="data5"><option></option><?php \
   $sql = "SELECT nome FROM raddb.Utente ORDER BY nome ASC"; \
   $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); \
   while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){ \
   echo "<option value=".$ln[\'nome\'].">".$ln[\'nome\']."</option>"; \
   }?></select></td>';
   html += '</tr>';
  });
```

or, I would recommend this,

```
$('#add1').click(function(){
   var html = '<tr>';
   html += '<td contenteditable ><input type="date" class="input-date" id="data1"/></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable><input type="text" class="input-day" id="data2"/></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable ><input type="time" id="data3"/></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable><input type="time"  id="data4"/></td>';
   html += `<td contenteditable><select id="data5"><option></option><?php
   $sql = "SELECT nome FROM raddb.Utente ORDER BY nome ASC";
   $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
   while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
   echo "<option value=".$ln['nome'].">".$ln['nome']."</option>";
   }?></select></td>`;
   html += '</tr>';
  });
```

> But, if you want execute the PHP code then check your server, because Its probably not working. If it did then you should not get PHP code in the browser.

Else please describe your problem more precisely,

- Do you want to exec the PHP code??
- Or, it is already executed??
- Or, Do you want to show the PHP code in your html??

Comment: None of the solutions worked. The problem is that this code already worked

Comment: What do you mean it worked. then whats was the point of your questtion??

Answer (score 0):

First I suggest you to add parentheses around attribute value:

```
echo "<option value=\"".$ln['nome']."\">".$ln['nome']."</option>";
```

And it will be much more helpful, if you have said what the error do you have?
You can always see html source code generated by the php script.

Comment: Returns this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" but says nothing more about it

Comment: Who returns? php? JavaScript processor in browser?